# PostgreQSL pg_dump with specific user

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a backup script for a PostgreSQL database. I want to execute the script by a cron job. 
First I created a system user "backup" 
In psql I executed the following statements:

```
CREATE USER backup;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE confluence TO backup;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO backup;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;
```

First of all was there any fatal error in above statements or is there a serious security issue? 
Is it right that the user backup is a read-only user? That was what I read in a tutorial but to be honest I have no idea what SCHEMA / schemes are...

When executing pg_dump as user backup I get the following:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation EVENTS
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public."EVENTS" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

As I am a absolute noob to databases I want to ask you before I add more and more statements without knowing what I do...

I am running psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5 on Ubuntu 10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04

Comment: Why not use the superuser for this ? It will prevent and privilege issues

Comment: I read about security issues and that it is best practice to have a separate user for that. BTW I didn't want to put the sudo passwort into the backup script